# Java Native Interface and Windows Form

Tags: java, c++, winforms, java-native-interface

So, i have visual studio consloe project that compile to .dll file. 
I've created simple windows form `System::Windows::Forms::Form`

I've created a .java file:

```
 import java.io.Serializable;


public class MyBean implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("MyBean");
}
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private static native String getDateCpp();


    public String getDate(){
        return getDateCpp();
    }



}
```

compiled it and generate a .h file by javah:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class MyBean */

#ifndef _Included_MyBean
#define _Included_MyBean
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#undef MyBean_serialVersionUID
#define MyBean_serialVersionUID 1i64
/*
 * Class:     MyBean
 * Method:    getDateCpp
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_MyBean_getDateCpp
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

and implemented a .cpp file that shows Form:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include "Form1.h"
#include "MyBean.h"
#include <string>
#include <vcclr.h>
using namespace std;


bool To_string( String^ source, string &target )
{
    pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars( source );
    int len = (( source->Length+1) * 2);
    char *ch = new char[ len ];
    bool result = wcstombs( ch, wch, len ) != -1;
    target = ch;
    delete ch;
    return result;
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_MyBean_getDateCpp
    (JNIEnv * env, jclass jcl){
        Form1^ form = gcnew Form1();
        form->Show();

        String^ text = form->text;
        string stdString = "";


        if(To_string(text,stdString))
            return  (*env).NewStringUTF(stdString.c_str());
        else
            return (*env).NewStringUTF("blad");
}
```

after compilling succesfully i'm getting error form java after i try to call c++ function:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007f9324f811c, pid=4404, tid=4800
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x3811c]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\studia\semestr 7\java\lab05\hs_err_pid4404.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

and log is long, i'll not post it here.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with your code but it could be vastly simpler. On Windows, Java uses code-unit-counted, UTF-16LE-encoded Unicode strings. .NET uses code-unit-counted, UTF-16LE-encoded Unicode strings....bliss. So, get the "length" of the .NET string, pin it with `PtrToStringChars` and pass that info to `env->NewString`; unpin and you're done. (NewStringUTF and GetStringCharsUTF use the _modified_ UTF_8 encoding, which is a crutch for non-Unicode functions.)

Comment: Thanks, your comment is very value but it works, as i mentioned below answer, problem was with `show()`, i should use `showDialog()`

Comment: "It works," really? Paste "You win a trip to Bangkok and ฿150,000" into your TextBox and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one mistake I'm calling `form->Show();` but I should call `form->ShowDialog();`

From MSDN:

> ShowDialog()
>
> You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your
> application. When this method is called, the code following it is not
> executed until after the dialog box is closed.

and

> Show()
>
> Showing the control is equivalent to setting the Visible
> property to true. After the Show method is called, the Visible
> property returns a value of true until the Hide method is called.

So, when I was calling show I got empty String to conversion and my window was showing only for a second or less, now it is modal and it waits for closing, then rest of code is executed. JNI was implemented properly and works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Uhh..

1. `wcstombs` never returns a value less than 0. See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/wcstombs/
2. This is tagged c++ so I think you should be using `env->` instead of `(*env).`. No big deal but meh..
3. I'm not sure if you need it but I think you're missing `extern "C"` before your JNI function.

Finally, make sure your calling convention is correct. I had the same problem/exception/dump a while back: [Loading JNI Dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484770/loading-jni-dll)

I solved it by changing the calling convention and exporting using a .def file. I believe all you need to fix it is just the calling convention. No need for the .def file; just thought I'd mention it anyway.

Whenever you get that error, it is due to calling convention issues. Rarely is it due to permissions but that is also something to look at. Perhaps you might need to run as administrator.

Comment: Ok, i'll check your advices. And i have `extern "C"` in my .h file, should I add that in .cpp file too?

Comment: Error was simple. I should use `showDialog()` not `show()`, now it works, thanks for tips and help.